# Is there a .NET library for file compare and that returns enumerable collections off added, changed and deleted lines?

Tags: c#, .net, merge

Is there a (preferably free) .NET library for file compare and that returns enumerable collections off added, changed and deleted lines?

Basically everything beyond compare does but in .NET and returns collections you can interact with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is a Diff generation library.

I would take a look at [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/).

You'll have to read the files into memory yourself, but it wouldn't be hard to build a wrapper class around DiffPlex so that you can easily use files from that point on...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried looking at DiffPlex, but find that there are a lack of code examples when it comes to Windows forms. I've tried to use the side-by-side but having serious difficulty implementing it. I've even tried contacting author but to no avail. The only sample code example I can find was using the InlineDiffBuilder class from [DiffPlex](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex).

It talks about a side-by-side example but only gives you an image. It would be really great if there were more tutorials and examples for this awesome code.

Comment: Hi there, did you ever find an example for Side by Side? Would love to see it :)